# AWS OpsWorks - Slow commands

Tags: aws-opsworks

My OpWorks commands are taking anywhere between 8-15 minutes for a single instance. This is extremely painful for deployments which should really only take 2-3 minutes.

Are these timings usual for a PHP application with no extra deployment recipes?

Comment: Can you post some opsworks logs ? If it's just happening on one server , but not others, it's a server that had too many noisy neighbours. Kill it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you are not using a t1.* or t2.* instance. Those instances can get really slow if you have depleted cpu credits (their CPU capacity are throttled).

Setup tasks performed by OpsWorks can deplete CPU capacity in those instances, before they are ready for service.

Comment: You are right. My m3 instances can do the commands in less than 4 minutes. Is there anything which can be done to speed up the commands on t1 instances? I understand that is the point of t1 is that it is slow.

Comment: I've found it's usually a matter of try and error. Usually the first thing that opsworks do in any new instance is to run recipes and some library installation. Those tasks use a lot of CPU. You might try to use a custom pre-created AMI, in order to minimize the number of recipes that OpsWorks has to do in the setup stage, but I think that's too much work and the result is uncertain. I suggest using m1.small, that has a stable performance and low cost.

Comment: This is a very good article about CPU throttling in AWS: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/concepts_micro_instances.html